# Prove The Set Of Absolutely Integrable Functions Is A Vector Space

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove: $V=\{f \text{  }|\text{  } f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \text{$f$ is absolutely integrable over $\mathbb{R}$}\}$ is a vector space

Let $\int|f(x)|dx,\int|g(x)|dx,\int|h(x)|dx\in V$ and $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\in \mathbb{R}$

1.$$\int|f(x)|dx+\int|g(x)|dx=\int (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)dx$$ from linearity of the integral and therefore $$\int (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)dx\in V$$

2. $$\alpha \int |f(x)|dx=\int \alpha |f(x)|dx$$
   from linearity of the integral and therefore $$\int \alpha|f(x)|dx\in V$$
3. $$\int|f(x)|dx+(\int|g(x)|dx+\int|h(x)|dx)=(\int|f(x)|dx+\int|g(x)|dx)+\int|h(x)|dx$$ As it is above $\mathbb{R}$ which is a field
4. $$\int|f(x)|dx+\int|g(x)|dx=\int|g(x)|dx+\int|f(x)|dx$$ As it is above $\mathbb{R}$ which is a field
5. $$0+\int|f(x)|dx=\int|f(x)|dx$$
6. $$\int|f(x)|dx-\int|f(x)|dx=0$$
7. $$(\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2})\int|f(x)|dx=\alpha_{1}\int\alpha_{2}|f(x)|dx$$
   from linearity of the integral
8. $$1\cdot\int|f(x)|dx=\int|f(x)|dx$$
9. $$\alpha_{1}(\int|f(x)|dx+\int|g(x)|dx)=\alpha_{1}(r_{f}+r_{g})=\alpha_{1}r_{f}+\alpha_{1}r_{g}=\alpha_{1}\int|f(x)|dx+\alpha_{1}\int|g(x)|dx$$ where $r_{f},r_{g}\in \mathbb{R}$

All the vector space axioms are fulfilled and therefore $V$ is a vector space.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Note that $V$ is a space of functions. The absolute integrals of those functions are finite, but the integral itself is a scalar.

Comment: You have not showed that $f,g\in V\implies f+g\in V.$ Note that $|f+g|\le |f|+|g|.$

Answer (score 2):

No it's not valid. The only thing that you have to prove is that if $f,g\in V$ and $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R$ implies that $\alpha f+\beta g\in V$. The rest follow fro the fact the set of function is a vector (what you could prove if you don't know it).

Comment: And since $|\alpha f+\beta g|\le |\alpha||f|+|\beta||g|$ one gets that ...

Comment: @mfl it is not a vector space?

Comment: It is a vector space. But you need to prove it. That is, as @Surb says in his answer, you need to show $f,g\in V,\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R\implies\alpha f+\beta g\in V$. And $|\alpha f+\beta g|\le |\alpha||f|+|\beta||g|$ is the way to do it. Why?

Comment: Because $\int|\alpha f+\beta g|\leq \alpha \int|f|+\beta \int|g|<\infty $.@mfl

Answer (score 1):

You have two options to show that $V$ is a vector space.

First one:

$$f,g\in V,\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R\implies\alpha f+\beta g\in V.$$

Second one:

$$f,g\in V\implies f+ g\in V\\f\in V,\alpha \in \mathbb R\implies\alpha f\in V.$$

In the first case we have that

$$|\alpha f+\beta g|\le |\alpha||f|+|\beta||g|\implies \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\alpha f+\beta g|\le |\alpha|\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|+|\beta|\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|<\infty,$$ which shows $$f,g\in V,\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb R\implies\alpha f+\beta g\in V.$$

In the second case we have that

$$|f+g|\le |f|+|g|\implies \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f+g|\le \int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|+\int_{\mathbb{R}}|g|<\infty,$$ which shows $$f,g\in V\implies f+ g\in V$$ and $$|\alpha f|= |\alpha||f|\implies \int_{\mathbb{R}}|\alpha f|= |\alpha|\int_{\mathbb{R}}|f|<\infty,$$ which shows $$f\in V,\alpha \in \mathbb R\implies\alpha f\in V.$$

Answer (score 0):

> Let $\int|f(x)|dx,\int|g(x)|dx,\int|h(x)|dx\in V$ and $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2}\in \mathbb{R}$
>
> `(This assumption does not make sense: you meant either` $f,g,h\in V$ `or` $\int|f(x)|dx<\infty,\int|g(x)|dx\infty,\int|h(x)|dx<\infty$`.)`
>
> 1.$$\int|f(x)|dx+\int|g(x)|dx=\int (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)dx$$ from linearity of the integral and therefore $$\int (|f(x)|+|g(x)|)dx\in V$$
>
> `(Again, the last expression is nonsense. You might want to apply the triangle inequality to conclude that` $f+g\in V$`.)`
>
> 2. $$\alpha \int |f(x)|dx=\int \alpha |f(x)|dx$$
>      from linearity of the integral and therefore 
>      $$
>    \int \alpha|f(x)|dx\in V
>    $$
>
> `(Again, the last expression is nonsense. You want to conclude that` $\int \alpha|f(x)|dx<\infty$`.)`
>
> `(I would stop reading from here. Note that` $V$ `is a subset of the vector space` ${\bf R}^{\bf R}$`. All the rest of your proof is redundant: you don't need to check other axioms.)`

---

Is this a valid proof? `(Not yet.)`